# Broken git repo - cannot set git revisions to last revision

Tags: git, repository, branch, branching-and-merging

I have done something wrong and now I would like the MASTER, bitbucket/MASTER and origin/MASTER to point to the origin, how should I do it? I thought everything is going to be solved by merging the branches but apparently I was wrong. Why do the three revisions stay behind?

Thanks a lot for your help :)
[image: Git status]

Answer (score 0):

You’re currently on the branch “origin” (that’s an odd name for a branch btw). That branch is ahead of the branch “MASTER” and the remote branches “MASTER” of both your bitbucket and origin remote. So merging any of those branches from the current situation will not do anything since they are already merged in (since you are *ahead* of them).

Instead, you want to check out the “MASTER” branch, fast-forward merge that to the “origin” branch and then push to your two remotes to update them too:

```
git checkout MASTER
git merge origin
git push bitbucket MASTER
git push origin MASTER
```